# Different header layout on desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to create a header that will be laid out differently on desktop and mobile, but my knowledge has taken me to a bit of a dead-end.

I can design both layouts, but don't know how I should switch between them, as this is a difference in HTML, not CSS so I can't just use media queries.
I'm trying to do this: [image]

The first one is on desktop. As you can see, nav links is between icons 1 and 2.
Option two is mobile and nav links should be under icon 1, title, and icon 2.

Desktop:

```css
* {border: 1px solid black;}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
   width: 10%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/aneheli/aneheli1501/aneheli150100030/35379090-artistic-sliced-lying-pineapple-on-orange-background-square-shot.jpg">
  <div>
    <h1>My Website.com</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/930/997/a0a.png">
</header>
```

Mobile:

```css
* {border: 1px solid black;}
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
   width: 10%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/aneheli/aneheli1501/aneheli150100030/35379090-artistic-sliced-lying-pineapple-on-orange-background-square-shot.jpg">
    <h1>My Website.com</h1>
    <img src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/930/997/a0a.png">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Beep Boop</li>
      <li>Making the header</li>
      <li>Too long to fit inside</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The key difference is that the nav links are inside the images on Desktop,. There is plenty of widths for them to push the images apart as wide as they need, but you can't do that on mobile, so the mobile solution puts the nav links underneath. The problem is that the header is too tall on desktop with the mobile solution.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: This can be done using media queries. Why not? The markup can be identical.

Comment: How is this if the nav is in the div in one option and outside in another?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Markup also needs to be prepared for what you're planning to achieve. Basically the difference between the two is that the navlinks should be displayed as blocks in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Grids to achieve this. If you don't know about it this a good guide:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Basically update your html to something like this

```
<header>
  <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/aneheli/aneheli1501/aneheli150100030/35379090-artistic-sliced-lying-pineapple-on-orange-background-square-shot.jpg" class="img-left">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>My Website.com</h1>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <img src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/930/997/a0a.png" class="img-right">
</header>
```

What you're doing here is putting all your elements directly under the header.

Now update your CSS, remove all the flex-box styling and include CSS grids

```
header {
  justify-content: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
              "img1 title img2"
              "img1 nav img2";
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
}

.img-left {
  grid-area: img1;
}

.img-right {
  grid-area: img2;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}
```

Here we're defining a grid and applying all the elements towards it.

Some additional updates I made to your CSS

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

//Removed this
div {...}
```

And finally, update your grid template for mobile

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  header {
    grid-template-areas:
              "img1 title img2"
              "nav nav nav";
  }
}
```